# How can i get the dynamic device output volume(the green volume bar on Volume Mixer panel)of win10 by python?

Tags: python, windows

How can i get the dynamic device output volume(the green volume bar on Volume Mixer panel) value of win10 by python?

[image: the green volume bar on Volume Mixer panel]

i want to get this value and control it if it too loudly or too small automatically.